# HTTP server, SYN flooding, and DoS attack questions

Tags: linux, http, denial-of-service

I am making an http server in c. It is in a pre-alpha stage but seemed to be stable enough to deploy on my server and run 4 minimal websites. It has been running seamlessly for two days until this morning. The daemon was not running and did not exit cleanly. I looked in the logs and found about 10 lines in a row saying:

```
[815259.230706] possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
```

Then no more messages logged from the http server, so i am assuming this is where it died. I am not sure what signal it received that killed it so I am assuming it was SIGKILL, SIGSEGV, or SIGABRT because they are not caught, and SIGKILL can't be caught anyway. I looked up SYN flooding and it's a type of DoS attack. I am not sure if the server was actually attacked or not but the most requests I receive in total for my 4 websites runs about at most 1 per second...not anywhere near enough to be falsely accused of being a DoS attack.

My questions are:

How likely is it that this was a DoS attack?

Would the kernel(linux) have killed the http server because of this or did it die on its own?

If the kernel killed it how do i prevent this from happening, i can't have it dieing unexpectedly?

If the kernel did not kill it, was the death likely caused by the SYN flooding and how can i debug it, or is it more likely it is an unrelated programming bug?

What security measures should i take to prevent possible SYN flooding?

EDIT:
The http server has now crashed 3 times with the same scenario occurring.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2827

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel is sending a SYN cookie to the remote machine which is doing de posible attack but not to your web server.

You can read [Hardening the TCP/IP stack to SYN attacks](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1729) to learn more about SYN flooding attacks.

Also maybe you want to read [this guide](http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html) about apache debugging and apply some ideas to debug your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Run netstat and see what the status of the connections are.  If you see a lot of SYN_RECV sockets just sitting there, there is a good chance your under a DOS.  If all the connections are coming from the same ip the fix is simple.

It's also possible your site has become popular or is being crawled by a poorly coded search bot resulting in a lot of connections and your server cannot handle it.  A search for "Linux tcp tuning" in your favourite search engine will turn up lots of hints/tips/how-tos on tuning your servers tcp stack.